# Larger payloads failing on HTTP POST

Tags: c#, http-post

I have code performing an HTTP POST to a vendor's site using WebClient.UploadValues.  When the payload is somewhere under 1.6 MB in size, the response is some XML data as expected.  When larger, the response from the vendor's site is null.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] response = client.UploadValues(strTargetUri, paramsNameValueCollection);
```

The vendor indicates they routinely receive larger payloads.  I can't find any IIS or WCF settings that would be limiting outgoing payload by size or time.  If I were exceeding a limit I set, .NET would throw an exception, not just return null.

Any suggestions of what I might be missing on my side?  Or something I should be sharing with the vendor?

**UPDATE**
I've received back samples received at the vendor end.  When under ~2MB, they show that they receive straight up XML such as:

```
<STAT>  
    <REQUEST _SEQUENCE_ID="1">
        <CUSTOMER>...
```

But when larger, it 1) is URL encoded, 2) is still preceded by other query string components and 3) contains some of the embedded "add-on" XML such as XML namespace references:

```
integrator=MyVal&userId=MyUser&password=12345&payload=%3cSTAT+xmlns%3axsd%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2fXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3axsi%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2fXMLSchema-instance%22%3e%3cREQUEST+_SEQUENCE_ID%3d%221%22...
```

My simplistic understanding of POSTs and the fact that I set nothing differently between scenarios makes me think the difference is because the vendor's processing software has "choked" and showing them different results.  I'm getting my net eng team to help me with tracking out outgoing packets to see if we can verify what we're sending at the last moment.

Comment: can you trace the actual response over the network using fiddler or similar? you should be able to get a HTTP response code. (not null - interpreted by your framework)

Comment: I don't have direct access.  My network engineering team reviewed the posts and saw the traffic leaving without issue.  I'll check if there's anything more they can tell me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

John,

The limit is most likely the server, so you may have to contact the vendor.  For example, the default max, non multipart, POST size of a Tomcat server is only 2MB.  If you can detect that the server is Tomcat, you could suggest that they increase the maxPostSize attribute of the Connnector.

Joe